# What is this fox fork front axle part called and where can I find a replacement?

Tags: fork, through-axle, fox

I've got a fox 36 talas RC2 from year 2006 and it's missing one of those black threaded inserts that pinches the front axle :

[image]

[image]

the part is M5 threaded, and approx. 28mm x 8.05mm

How is this called and where can I find a replacement? Is there an archive of parts numbers like for cars somewhere? I've only managed to find year 2015+ square pinch inserts so far like this one :

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the bolts used are M5 (test against the one you have), a barrel-shaped seatpost clamp nut might work. Maybe your local bike shop has one lying around?

Comment: Hello that was a good idea, i tried with my own seatpost nuts and they are slightly too big for the hole in the fork. is diameter of that nut standard?

Comment: It looks like a fairly straightforward part to make.  If you've got an example, its even easier.  The critical measurements are the hole size/thread, distance apart, and that the whole thing fits into the space in the fork

Comment: I would love to make it if I knew how and had the proper tools, I am no machinist.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Not all seatpost nuts have the same diameter. I'd check with a (patient) and dedicated LBS mechanic or maybe a local repair commune. Most of them have part-bin-treasure troves. And if the diameter is only very slightly too big (0.1mm) careful reaming of paint inside the hole might suffice.

Comment: Were you ever able to find the correct Fox part? If not, were you able to use a furniture barrel bolt instead? I have lost across pin on my Fox40RC2 Fit as well. I am having a difficult time locating part #229-19-030 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. Local fox service shop told me the reference is 229-19-030 and they call it "cross-pin axle", as can be seen on [this dealer](http://www.sabma.com/fox-cross-pin-axle-36-c2x22460160) :

[image]

I was also able to find nuts with 8mm OD that could fit on a well known [marketplace](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000794306509.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000014.11.77653c548HKnAu&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.14976.193957.0&scm_id=1007.14976.193957.0&scm-url=1007.14976.193957.0&pvid=1bcc0499-0260-48de-a2e4-78548fc9ec26&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.14976.193957.0,pvid:1bcc0499-0260-48de-a2e4-78548fc9ec26,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%230_668%23808%234094%23117_668%23888%233325%2315_4976%230%23193957%233_4976%232711%237538%23931_4976%233104%239652%231_4976%234052%2318550%2338_4976%233141%239887%239_668%232846%238112%23567_668%232717%237567%23919_668%231000022185%231000066059%230_668%233422%2315392%2394_4452%230%23189847%230_4452%233474%2315675%23675_4452%233098%239599%23631_4452%233564%2316062%23919)
[image]

Fox says to apply very little torque on that part and that it is just to prevent the axle from going loose so it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer!

Comment: Very late to the party, but for holding something rather critical like the wheel into the front fork, I'd think it'd be worth a few extra bucks for the OEM parts as opposed to "cheap items of unknown quality".

Answer (score 4):

The one you have pictured is called a "pinch bar" or an "axle pinch bar"

[image]

I was unable to find a vendor who sells a 2006 version like yours. The one on your fork appears to be rounded. The newer ones appear to be square - like the last picture in your post. [Here is a link to a vendor with a 2015 version](https://www.worldwidecyclery.com/pages/search-results-page?q=pinch%20bar) (not a recommendation).

Here is a [link to a 2005 manual](https://www.ridefox.com/fox_tech_center/owners_manuals/05_36_en.pdf) for your fork. Sadly it does not list the pinch bolt anywhere but it has other information that may help.

Comment: Is it harmful to ride without the axle properly pinched?

Comment: @John Doe, Yes, your front wheel may fall out. Standard M5 nuts might actually fit, but I would not personally feel safe riding such a hack.